# How to share wired network connection in 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, 18.04, ethernet

I had been sharing my network connection through my computer (previously windows 10) with two other computers using usb-ethernet adaptors, and I can't get it to work now that my host computer is running Ubuntu 18.04.

The three wired connections appear in network settings as expected, but I don't know how to configure them to share internet and network.

Tutorials on the internet show a different network settings UI, with IPv4 Settings tab Method: "Shared to other computers". I don't have the option "Shared to other computers" and "Link-Local Only" does not seem to work.

How can I share one wired connection with two others?

Comment: To anyone who comes here and is still lost there's a good tutorial [here](https://www.crookm.com/journal/2018/sharing-wifi-connection-over-ethernet/) that explains the process.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The graphical program that shows the feature you need is

`nm-connection-editor`

You can launch it from a terminal window or with Alt+F2

Higlight an adapter and hit the cog

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed, now it works perfectly.

Comment: how do you do this from terminal, without gui ?

Comment: If you see `Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused` check if you're in something like tmux and missing `$DISPLAY`.

Answer (score 7):

To anyone who comes here and is still lost on what to do, I found a tutorial that explains it [here](https://www.crookm.com/journal/2018/sharing-wifi-connection-over-ethernet/).

### Basic rundown

First run `nm-connection-editor` in your terminal.

Next, you will see a screen that lists a bunch of different network devices.

[image: picture of network connection list]

Click on your wired connection and then click on the cog at the bottom of the window.

A window will open giving you a bunch of options to edit the connection.
Go to the IPV4 settings tab and change the method to share to other computers. Finally hit save.

[image: Picture of connection editor]

You should be all set to go! **It's important to note that you may have to unplug and replug your network cable or reset the connection in order for it to work.**

Answer (score 2):

Using `nm-connection-editor` set the usb-ethernet connections under IPv4 Settings to `Shared to other computers`. Leave the internet ethernet connection alone.

For context, I wanted to give a USB ethernet (eth1) gadget (Pi Zero) access to the internet by sharing the PCI ethernet (eth0) internet connection. However, the only way I could get it working was to set eth1 to `Shared ...`, the total opposite of what I expected the setup to be.